Change displayed Variable Product Attributes on WooCommerce Shop Page
I found some code that show variable product attributes on WooCommerce  shop page:
/**
 * Replace add to cart button in the loop.
 */
function iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

/**
 * Use single add to cart button for variable products.
 */
function iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
        return;
    }

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

    woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
}

/**
 * Customise variable add to cart button for loop.
 *
 * Remove qty selector and simplify.
 */
function iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
    </div>
    <?php
}

I get the following display:

How can I remove the "Marime" text string (meaning "Size"), while keeping the size numbers and make them displayed horizontally?
I would like to have the following display:


To achieve the desired changes, we need to modify the PHP code, could you please try to replace your code with the given code in your functions.php file.
The given code helps you in removing the "Marime" text string (meaning "Size"), while keeping the size numbers.
<?php

/**
 * Here we are replacing add to cart button in the loop.
 */
function iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart () {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

/**
 * Here we are using single add to cart button for variable products.
 */
function iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
        return;
    }

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

    // Here we are displaying custom variations.
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart' );
    woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
}

/**
 * Here we are displaying custom variable product attributes.
 */
function custom_woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();

        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) {
            ?>
            <div class="custom-variation-attribute">
                <?php
                // Here we are outputing options without label.
                foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                    ?>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $attribute_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option ); ?>" />
                        <?php echo esc_html( $option ); ?>
                    </label>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Here we are customising variable add to cart button for loop.
 *
 * Here we are removing qty selector and simplify.
 */
function iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
    </div>
    <?php
}


Also please add the given CSS code to style.css file of the theme. This will helps you in making the numbers show horizontally.


.custom-variation-attribute {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    /* Adjust the spacing as per your need */
}
.custom-variation-attribute label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-variation-attribute input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 5px;
    /* Adjust the spacing as per your need */
}
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations td.label {
    display: none !important;
}
td.value .attribute-swatch {
    display: flex;
}
.woo-variation-swatches.wvs-show-label .variations td label {
    margin: .5px !important;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: small;
}
.woo-variation-swatches.wvs-show-label .variations td.value {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}




Thank you for your reply,
ive added everything correctly but it seems like it is not working,
i tried adjusting the spacing in the CSS code and still no changes.
I have also added your php code and the results are the same as my php code.
Thank you for you patience

Could you please share the URL of the webpage where I can take a closer look to this.

Questions should not relay on external resources to be solved. There is no point in asking a direct link to the website. Furthermore how does this wall of code solve the issue? Please explain the answer

The code PHP code will remove the "Marime" text string (meaning "Size"), while keeping the size numbers. The CSS code make them displayed horizontally.

please add all details inside the answer

I have done the changes.

@NarendraSishodiya  https://woocommerce-1274098-4667838.cloudwaysapps.com/ this is the page

Could you please try to add given code to functions.php file of your theme.
`function remove_swatch_title_label_class( $content ) {
$content = preg_replace('/<([^>])(\sclass="[^"]\bswatchtitlelabel\b[^"]")([^>])>/i', '<$1$3>', $content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_swatch_title_label_class');`

I tried it but unfortunately still the same.. no luck

Could you please try to add given CSS code to Appearances > Customize > Additional CSS.
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations td.label {display: none!important;}

I did that and it removed the "marime" text.
The numbers are still vertical

It's coming fine at my end, please let me know if I am missing anything.
Desktop : https://ibb.co/ngQRhzQ
Mobile : https://ibb.co/jvxRCW7

The problem is not on the product page, it is in the shop page  https://woocommerce-1274098-4667838.cloudwaysapps.com/

or the catalog page : https://woocommerce-1274098-4667838.cloudwaysapps.com/product-category/incaltaminte/

Thanks for the URL,
Could you please try to add given CSS code to Appearances > Customize > Additional CSS.
td.value .attribute-swatch{display:flex;}

It worked, thank you so much.. one more question i have is how do i make it a bit smaller since its a bit out of the product box.

Welcome, could you please share the screenshot and URL so I can check the issue.

ok here is the image: https://imgur.com/a/PC801mD and the page is https://woocommerce-1274098-4667838.cloudwaysapps.com/

Please try to replace above two codes with the given one.
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations td.label {display: none!important;}td.value .attribute-swatch{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;}
it should work for you.

I did that but it stacks them on eachother: https://imgur.com/a/oSJm5AS,
is it possible to look similar to this? keeping it vertical just making it smaller a bit: https://imgur.com/a/EQqu0jh
Thank you for your patience!

Thanks for the details, Could you please try to add given CSS code to Appearances > Customize > Additional CSS.
.woo-variation-swatches.wvs-show-label .variations td label {margin: 1px!important;border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;font-size: small;}

I did that and it looks great! the thing is it still stacks over one and other, i believe it is because of {flex-wrap:wrap}.
Is there a way to keep the numbers in a line, vertical without stacking them on top of eachother?
thanks

Please remove the flex-wrap:wrap and also replace margin: 1px!important with margin: .5px!important and then add the given CSS code.
.woo-variation-swatches.wvs-show-label .variations td.value{padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;}

It worked!! its perfect, thank you so much for your patience man.
Last question that i have is: https://imgur.com/a/WNJTDqR
I tried to remove the add to cart button "adauga in cos" but failed do you know how to remove it from shop page https://woocommerce-1274098-4667838.cloudwaysapps.com/ for simple products and variable products.
thank you so much, if you dont, its ok you helped me immensely

Please mark this question resolved if your issue fixed by solutions.

For that issue you can add given CSS code to Appearances > Customize > Additional CSS.
.woocommerce .rh-flex-eq-height .single_add_to_cart_button, .woocommerce div.product form.cart .button {display: none!important;}.rh-flex-eq-height a.woo_loop_btn.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart {display: none!important;}

Thank you, i checked the catalog page and the numbers exceed the product box: https://imgur.com/a/xzy67CP only while in mobile view, the page link is: https://woocommerce-1274098-4667838.cloudwaysapps.com/product-category/incaltaminte/

Please try to add given CSS code to Appearances > Customize > Additional CSS.
@media (max-width: 479px) {.product.col_item.two_column_mobile.type-product.woo_mart{width: 100% !important;}}

Having that code implemented will remove the ability to have 2 product grid and showcase only 1 product. https://imgur.com/a/Js1Cm9T.
https://imgur.com/a/JlTHv1o
Maybe having the font smaller will fix the issue?

Reducing the fonts will not help because there is already min-width set in the tag. Please find the attached screenshot.
https://ibb.co/C6zQ4J7

oh i understand.

do you know of any other way that this could be fixed?

For this we need to edit and removed that from plugin file which is not the recommended way because it has been gone on plugin update.
